# Reference UID for the file (sys_file_reference) has to be numeric

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I am trying to migrate a website from Typo3 4.0 to a fresh new server with Typo3 8.7. I have exported the tree structure from the root page on the old CMS, selecting all levels and tables. When I try to import it on the new CMS I get the following error:

`The reference UID for the file (sys_file_reference) has to be numeric`

I found [this](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/58693) bug report, which states that the bug has been updated for version 6.2. How can I avoid having `sys_file_reference` records with relations to `sys_files` records during the export? Or is there another way to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 6.0 the file handling of TYPO3 has changed drastically: FAL was introduced.

As of this change you cannot transfer data from an older version to a newer one. you need to do an update in place.
The neccessary way would be:

1. make a clone of your 4.0 installation
2. update to 4.5 (this should be easy as till then not much was deprecated)
3. update to 6.2 (in this upgrade all file references are transformed into FAL)
4. update to 8.7 [1]

For Step 3 and 4 you may need to update extensions and their data to a matching version.

[1] you wrote about 8.3. this was an intermediate version which is not support in any way.
Always use the latest version, which is 8.7 (for the 8 version) in the latest (current) subversion 8.7.8

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I'll try out the steps you have listed here. You are right, I've actually installed 8.7 on the new server, it was just a typo in the question text. I've fixed it now.